# how lambda works with reduce

Tags: python, python-2.7, lambda

I was trying to understand how `reduce` works through this website. The example they have mentioned is quite good and easy to understand.

http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html#reduce

```
a = reduce((lambda x, y: x * y), [1, 2, 3, 4])
```

The above function will multiple each and every number in list and assign to `a`.

However, I got totally stumped when I came across following function in project.

```
def compose(*fns):
    return reduce(lambda acc, fn: lambda *args: acc(fn(*args)), fns, lambda _: _)
```

could someone help me breakdown this function to understand what it's suppose to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lambda` expressions can be difficult to follow, and especially so with this one, which returns a new function, also defined using `lambda`.

Here is that same expression, but with some different line spacing:

```
def compose(*fns):
    return reduce(lambda acc, fn: lambda *args: acc(fn(*args)), 
                  fns,
                  lambda _: _)
```

Now I'll further expand this by exploding the `lambda`s passed to `reduce` as a regular `def` statements:

```
def compose_2_fns(f, g):
    # take 2 functions and return a new function that calls the first with the
    # result of calling the second
    def composed(*args):
        return f(g(*args))
    return composed

def _initial(x):
    return x

def compose(*fns):
    return reduce(compose_2_fns, fns, _initial)
```

Recall that `reduce` works by giving it a method that takes 2 arguments, a sequence of objects (in this case, a sequence of functions), and an optional initial value.

```
reduce(reduce_fn, objs, first_obj)
```

If no initial value is given, reduce will take the first object in the sequence, as if you had called it like:

```
reduce(reduce_fn, objs[1:], objs[0])
```

Then the reduce function is called like this:

```
accumulator = first_obj
for obj in objs:
    accumulator = reduce_fn(accumulator, obj)
return accumulator
```

So what your posted `reduce` statement is doing is building up a big function by combining several smaller ones.

```
functions = (add_1, mult_5, add_3)
resulting_function -> lambda *args: add_1(mult_5(add_3(*args)))
```

So that:

```
resulting_function(2) -> (((2 + 3) * 5) + 1) -> 26
```

Comment: this was really hell of a confusing function. Thanks for making it really simple.

Answer (score 4):

Not very readable at first sight. Let's decompose:

First, `def compose(*fns):` means that the compose function will receive an unknown number of arguments.

Next, let's decompose the reduce function:

```
reduce(
   lambda acc, fn: lambda *args: acc(fn(*args)),
   fns,
   lambda _: _
)
```

As the [doc](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#reduce) indicates, `reduce` takes 3 arguments:

```
def reduce(function, iterable, initializer=None):
```

So, in your case: the `function` is `lambda acc, fn: lambda *args: acc(fn(*args))`, `fns` is the `iterable`, and it will be initialize with `lambda _: _`

The `initializer` indicates that the arguments of `compose` will be functions. `lambda _: _` is a "neutral element" for function (the same as "0" for addition or "1" for multiplication). I guess it's there essentially when fns is empty.

Now for the main part:

```
lambda acc, fn: lambda *args: acc(fn(*args))
```

this is a function that take two functions `acc` and `fn` and returns the lambda function `lambda *args: acc(fn(*args))`.

Let's take an example:

```
>>> reduce((lambda acc, fn: acc ** fn), [1, 2, 3, 4])
1
>>> reduce((lambda acc, fn: fn ** acc ), [1, 2, 3, 4])
262144
```

Here acc and fn are not function, but integers. `acc` is the "accumulated/reduced" so far, and `fn` is the "next" step.

With functions, it will be the same `acc` will be the "called functions" so far, and fn the next function.

So `lambda acc, fn: lambda *args: acc(fn(*args))` will return a (lambda) function, that will return `acc(fn(the_arguments))`.

`reduce(lambda acc, fn: lambda *args: acc(fn(*args)), fns, lambda _: _)` will then returns a function consisting of applying each functions of `fns` to its args, with identity by default (`lambda _: _`).

Let's take an example:

```
>>> def square(x):
...  return x**2
...
>>> def increment(x):
...   return x+1
...
>>> def half(x):
...   return x/2
...
>>> compose(square, increment, half)
<function <lambda> at 0x7f5321e13de8>
>>> g=compose(square, increment, half)
>>> g(5)
9
```

So, `g(x) = square(increment(half(x)))`

---

With [Kasramvd's example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45503865/3336968):

```
compose(max, min)([[2, 4], [3, 5]])
```

is the same as:

```
max(min([[2, 4], [3, 5]]))
```

`min([[2, 4], [3, 5]])` will returns `[2,4]` and `max([2,4])` is 4. Thus `compose(max, min)([[2, 4], [3, 5]])=4`

Comment: I like _"The `initializer` indicates that the arguments of `compose` will be functions. `lambda _: _` is a »neutral element« for function (the same as `0` for addition or `1` for multiplication). "_

Comment: super awesome explanation , @fredtantini

Answer (score 2):

That `reduce` is just a function composer. It accepts an iterable of functions and combines them.

One important point about the `reduce` is that when you pass 2 arguments to your function (in this case `acc`, `fn`) based on how you are using them, at first iteration python uses the last two arguments in your iterable instead of them, and in next iterations it uses the result of latest calculation instead of second argument passed to the `lamda` or any function passed as the constructor to the `reduce` (in this case `fn`). Now For a better demonstration here are all the arguments passed to the `reduce` in distinction:

the function: `lambda acc, fn: lambda *args: acc(fn(*args))`

- the use of second function is being able to pass the arguments to the inner function at each iteration.

iterable argument: `fns`

initial argument: `lambda _: _`

> If initial is present, it is placed before the items
>   of the sequence in the calculation, and serves as a default when the
>   sequence is empty.

As you can see in passed function it calls the inner functions with arguments and passes it to the next function like `fog` in mathematics which is `f(g(x))`. But since you can pass an undefined number of arguments to reduce this function can compose multiple function.

Here is an example:

```
In [10]: compose(max, min)([[2, 4], [3, 5]])
Out[10]: 4
```

Also note that this is not a pythonic and recommended way of composing the functions at all. Because first of all it's not readable and easily understandable secondly it's using a lot of extra function calls which is not optimum for such task.