# reduce function with lambda

Tags: python-3.x, lambda, reduce

I am trying to understand how reduce function works with lambda function

```
#argument digits can be "23" or "45"
def letterCombinations(self, digits):
        if '' == digits: return []
        kvmaps = {
            '2': 'abc',
            '3': 'def',
            '4': 'ghi',
            '5': 'jkl',
            '6': 'mno',
            '7': 'pqrs',
            '8': 'tuv',
            '9': 'wxyz'
        }
        return reduce(lambda acc, digit: [x + y for x in acc for y in kvmaps[digit]], digits, [''])
```

However, I got totally stumped when I came across return statement
could someone help me breakdown the return statement to understand what it's suppose to do

I have already gone through following link:
[how lambda works with reduce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45503434/how-lambda-works-with-reduce)

Q1 what will be the first value for acc (accumulator)? 
Q2 is my understanding ,iterator will only be used by second argument of lambda,correct ?
Q3: is the behavior of accumulator(acc) and second argument differs in case initializer is present or not?

Comment: Is the lambda really the problem here? ie would you understand the code if `reduce` was given a named function?

Comment: The answer to the question you linked to explains this beautifully. What exactly don't you understand after reading that answer?

Comment: @DeepSpace, question updated,

Answer (score 0):

All your questions are answered in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functools.html#functools.reduce).

```
reduce(lambda acc, digit: [x + y for x in acc for y in kvmaps[digit]], digits, [''])
```

> what will be the first value for acc (accumulator)?

In this case: `['']`, a list with an empty string.

> is my understanding, iterator will only be used by second argument of lambda, correct?

The second argument (`digit` in this case) is an individual element from the iterator provided, in this case `digits`.

> is the behavior of accumulator(acc) and second argument differs in case initializer is present or not?

No. The initializer is inserted before the the first element in the iterable. If the iterable is empty that initializer will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Fun example! Let us remove the self, add the import, and modify the lambda to understand better:

```
from functools import reduce
def letterCombinations(digits):
        if '' == digits: return []
        kvmaps = {
            '2': 'abc',
            '3': 'def',
            '4': 'ghi',
            '5': 'jkl',
            '6': 'mno',
            '7': 'pqrs',
            '8': 'tuv',
            '9': 'wxyz'
        }
        return reduce(lambda acc, digit: 
                      [x + y for x in acc for y in kvmaps[digit]],
                      digits, ['GLOUGLOU'])
```

So now if I test our function with

```
letterCombinations('4')
```

it answers

```
>>>['GLOUGLOUg', 'GLOUGLOUh', 'GLOUGLOUi']
```

So you see that it splits the letters g,h,i given by kvmaps['4'], and add them to 'GLOUGLOU'.

And if I replace

```
['GLOUGLOU']
```

by

```
['GLOUGLOU', 'DRINGDRING']
```

you will have

```
>>>['GLOUGLOUg',
 'GLOUGLOUh',
 'GLOUGLOUi',
 'DRINGDRINGg',
 'DRINGDRINGh',
 'DRINGDRINGi']
```

From there, you can see how reduce() works in your case with digit concatenation.

I hope that helps a little bit !